# How do I add compile sources via a run script build phase in XCode?

Tags: xcode, shell, build, compilation, project

I have an XCode project which I would like to add source files to via scripting.
Is it possible to add compile sources via a run script build phase?

If so, how would I go about this?

I haven't found any documentation or examples of this, so I'm not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create target that runs script. In this script any sources could be passed to xcodebuild arguments. 
If this is not what is needed, XCode project by itself is an xml, so any files could be added to any targets, but project should be reloaded after, so I don't know how to add files to target withing runnign this target build.